# How do I retrieve implemented objects from an array of interface from ASP.NET Core Web API ? And not just the properties that are in the interface

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to retrieve data from my MongoDb database using an ASP.NET Core Web API.

The object I'm trying to retrieve has an array of `IPanel`. And after retrieving it I want to access the `Text` property in the `TextPanel`,
or the `ImageUrl` in the `ImagePanel`.

Unfortunately the API only returns the properties defined in the interface.

TextPanel:

```
[BsonDiscriminator("TextPanel")]
public class TextPanel : IPanel
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; } = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string PageId { get; set; } = "Invalid PageId";

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; } = "Text here";

    public TextPanel(string title = "Title")
    {
        Title = title;
    }
}
```

ImagePanel:

```
[BsonDiscriminator("ImagePanel")]
public class ImagePanel : IPanel
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; } = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string PageId { get; set; } = "Invalid PageId";

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<string> ImageUrls { get; set; } = new();
    public List<string> ImageCaptions { get; set; } = new();

    public bool Cropping { get; set; }

    public ImagePanel(string title = "Title")
    {
        Title = title;
    }
}
```

IPanel:

```
public interface IPanel
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string PageId { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
}
```

ApiReturn:

```
{
  "id": "guid",
  "panels": [
    {
      "id": "guid",
      "pageId": "guid",
      "title": "TextPanel"
    },
    {
      "id": "guid",
      "pageId": "guid",
      "title": "TextPanel"
    }
  ]
}
```

PanelController:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddTextPanel")]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddTextPanel(string pageId, string? title)
{
    await panelService.AddTextPanel(pageId, title!);
    return Ok("Text Panel Added");
}
```

panelService.AddTextPanel:

```
public async Task AddTextPanel(string pageId, string title = "Title")
{
    BasePage page = pageService.GetPageById(pageId);
    TextPanel newPanel = new(title);
    page.AddPanel(newPanel);
    await pageService.UpdatePage(page);
}
```

page.AddPanel:

```
public void AddPanel(IPanel panel)
{
    panel.PageId = Id;
    Panels.Add(panel);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Comment: Changed them to code snippets.

Comment: Could you please share the web api related codes? If you just use ipanel as the web api controller method parameter, it will just bind the ipanel model's propertiy.